# I went to use map function inside a array but it's give me error

Tags: reactjs

(TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined)

### I went to use a map function in the image array. which I fetch by useEffect.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const { images, setImages } = useState();

  useEffect(() =>
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setImages(json)),
  )
  return (
    <div>
      {images.map(image => <img src={image.url} alt="boohoo" className="img-responsive" />)}
    </div>
  )
}
export default App;
```

Comment: `images` is only set once your fetch is complete, which will occur after the first render. Try default `images` using `const { images, setImages } = useState([]);`

Comment: Where are you updating your state for images?

Comment: You need to update your state for images after the response is fetched.Ex. setImage(response)

Comment: @techie_questie they're doing that here: `.then(json => setImages(json))`

Comment: @Nick Parsons, Oh correct, i overlooked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [ images, setImages ] = useState([]);  // setting the initial state as  [] array 

  useEffect(() =>
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setImages(json)),
  )
  return (
    <div>
      {images.map(image => <img src={image.url} alt="boohoo" className="img-responsive" />)}
    </div>
  )
}
export default App;
```

try this

Answer (score 2):

Please do add a null check for `images` since it is set after the fetch is completed which is an async operation, as during mount time images will be `null`.

```
 return (
<div>
  {images&&images.map(image => <img src={image.url} alt="boohoo" className="img-responsive" />)}
</div>)
```

or you can initialise the images with empty array in `useState` as

```
const { images, setImages } = useState([]);
```